# sed - perform multiple substitutions on a line found by pattern search?

Tags: sed

I have a file which contains a like like this:

```
name=MOD0
```

and a lot of extra lines which I'm not interested in.
I need to transform this line into this:

```
[MOD0]
```

and drop all other lines from the file.
The MOD0 part is not predictable, so I need to match the line by the ^name= pattern. I can perform one substitution (remove the "name="), but how do I tell sed to perform another operation (surround the line with brackets), still on the same matched line? The following command surrounds every line with brackets:

```
sed -n -e '/^name=/ s/^name=//p; s/^.*$/\[&\]/p'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use braces:

```
sed -n '
   /^name=/ {
     s///p
     s/.*/[&]/p
   }'
```

Note a blank search pattern (as in `s///p`) reuses the last pattern.

Alternatively:

```
 sed '/^name=/!d;s///p;s/.*/[&]/'
```

(that is delete the lines that don't start with `name=` and then process the other ones).

If you just want to replace the `name=xxx` with `[xxx]` without also outputting `xxx`, then you can just do:

```
sed -n 's/^name=\(.*\)/[\1]/p'
```

(or remove the `p` flag to the first `s` command in the other commands above).

Comment: This prints two lines for each match. You have to remove the first 'p' action in the first two solutions.

Comment: Thanks! :)
I managed to find out that multiple commands can be combined into blocks with braces, but the last command in your answer is simpler a does exactly what I need.

Comment: @danielkullmann, that was my assumption on what the OP wanted to do based on his example. I clarify that in the second part of the answer which is why I reversed your edit.